# handle search on large data in MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a C# Windows forms with a MySQL database.

I have to search through a large data in the table, which is taking almost 5-10 minutes to provide answer.(*It is taking same time when I run query on MySql query tools*)

Is there any searching technique by which I can make my search faster? Currently, I am using simple `select` statements with `where` clause. Can `Idictionary`, `hashtable` etc can be implemented with it?

Comment: Are you not using a WHERE clause?

Comment: Your SQL statements, along with the state of that table's indexes will provide the most help for answers to this question.

Comment: I am using _where_ _clause_ but there are above 100 thousand records.

Comment: it takes 5-10 minutes to execute the query also if you execute it from the my sql query tool or to render the whole grid of results in your User Interface?

Comment: @Davide Piras: Yes it is taking same time in MySQL query tool

Comment: Let's see this query. Gotta be something fishy there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding an index to the columns you are searching on in your where clause?

Are you searching through 100k records, or is your set returning 100k records. In modern computing 100k records is a drop in the bucket. Properly indexing columns can *greatly* speed up this process.

If your set is returning 100k records, conciser filtering further, even if it's only to return the top 10 records (make sure to order the results). Put all this in your SQL query and make MySql do all the heavy lifting for you. Generally speaking a user does not need to see 100k records at once.

To further answer your question, the results should be populated into CLR objects and those added to a collection of some sort. See `System.Collections.Generic.List`. Once they are in objects like this, handling the data from C# should be trivial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This.  You need to focus on the MYSQL database because that's where the work should be performed.  Tune your indexes.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: okie I ll try that. thanx

Comment: thanx .. I will apply index on my table and let you know i it works.

Answer (score -2):

If you can afford to put it in memory, Yes. Depending upon your search options you could apply algorithms to cache items most recently searched.

If caching is not an option you should look into properly indexing your database tables.

Correction:
Regardless of whether caching is or is not an option you should first optimize with proper indexing and statistics anyways.

Comment: Putting a large table in memory for doing a search means the entire table must be retrieved first.

Comment: Well, it depends. First time yes he may use efficient indexing, to prevent table scans and key look ups, second time onwards cached results may be his option to improve performance. It all depends upon specific requirements.

Comment: I dunno about you but when I think LARGE table I think 100k rows plus.  Even at a minuscule few bytes per row, you're talking about consuming massive amounts of memory to perform a data search a bit faster.  Having seen this kind of mindset used in real production environments, and the crippling performance results, I only wish I could downvote this answer more than once.

Comment: caching does not mean putting few bytes of all rows in memory.

Comment: AH you're talking about caching the RESULTS of the 5 minute search!  I'm sorry, I didn't get that from your answer at all at first.  Still - he still needs to address the actual query performance itself - 5-10 minutes wait time on a single db call isn't acceptable.

Comment: "5-10 minutes wait time on a single db call isn't acceptable" -  true.